# 3D Transformations on a Quartz2D path — Drawing Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, 3d, quartz-graphics, vector-graphics

I'm in the planning stage of writing a Cocoa drawing application (for Mac, not iOS), and I'm trying to discern whether one of my features is technically possible via any of the drawing frameworks. Any help or relevant information would be greatly appreciated.

The idea is to apply a 3D transformation to an object drawn with Quartz2D. I've considered capturing the relevant portion of the canvas View (where objects are drawn) as an image and sending it to Core Animation, but that doesn't seem like the best option. Since this is a drawing application, it's less about 3D animation than it is about the transformed shape. This solution is also less than ideal because I assume that if the 2D object were a vector path rather a bitmap image, I would have to rasterize it to apply such a transformation. The ideal implementation would enable the user to dynamically rotate a flat object in 3 dimensions until she found a suitable orientation, lock in this transformation, and still be able to manually adjust the path's vector points.

Is this feasible? Would it require working directly with OpenGL? Help of any kind is most welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that anything you'd do with a 3D transform, you should be able to do with multiple affine transforms.  See `UIBezierPath's` `-applyTransform` method.